# Need a coding logic to get output numbers based on input numbers

Tags: c#, logic

I am working on a C# program where I need certain output numbers for formatting a printable string. This will help me in determining on how many /r/n I need to add between different datasets internally.

It is in WinForms.

```
public int GiveMeOutput(int input)
{
    int output = 2;

    //logic here

    return output;
}
```

Can anyone help me in any language for the logic?
Greatly appreciate your help.

I would be getting the input into a Function(int input) & it should throw the "int" output.

Below is the table I want

| If Input is | Then Output should be |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 11 | 5 |
| 12 | 5 |
| 13 | 6 |
| 14 | 6 |
| ...continues | ...continues |

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve and what issue you are facing. You need table output but where? In Web Form, in Windows Form, in Report, sending in Email, in Pdf file? What is the input value and what's the logic of converting it output?

Comment: Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```cs
int Map(int input)
{
    return (input - 2 + input % 2) / 2;
}
```

Subtract 2, add 1 to odd numbers, then divide by 2.

Comment: You are the time saver John. I was banging my head for the past 2 hours trying out different things & I got closer till the modulus part but you added the final touch if division for rounding